# Displaying the id of the customer with the greatest amount of purchased products

Tags: postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have this db

https://pastebin.com/WWRxApWn

I did this

```
--SELECT a.id

--FROM (

SELECT customer.id,customer.firstname,customer.lastname,SUM(quantity) as sum
FROM (

    orders
    INNER JOIN Orderitem ON orders.id = orderitem.orderid
    INNER JOIN product ON product.id = orderitem.productid
    INNER JOIN Customer ON orders.customerid = customer.id
)

GROUP BY customer.id--) as a

--HAVING sum = (SELECT MAX(sum) FROM a)
;
```

I got this error when I uncomment the commented parts:

> relation "a" does not exist

I've tinkered with it quite a bit, every time I get one error or the other. How do I do this?

Comment: Don't link a pastebin (or any other external resource) as a [example]. Include the [example] (with special emphasis on complete and minimal for that matter) *in* the question *itself*.

Comment: @stickybit The file would fill up the whole OP.

Comment: It includes the attribute **minimal** and I even emphasized that already. Reduce it to the minimum needed to show the problem and post that minimum.

Comment: Besides that please also add a description what you want to query there and post the desired result with the (minimized!) sample data as tabular text. A wrong query doesn't necessarily clearly convey what you really want.

Answer (score 1):

If you need only the customer id with the greatest amount you could have it in the following way:

```
with
qt_summed as (
SELECT orders.customerid, SUM(orderitem.quantity) as sum
FROM orders
INNER JOIN Orderitem ON orders.id = orderitem.orderid
GROUP BY orders.customerid
order by sum desc
limit 1
)

select resource_id as id from qt_summed
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ORDER BY` in combination `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW` or `LIMIT 1` to get only the row with maximum `SUM(quantity)`. Further notes:

- There may be more than customers with the same (max) number of items purchased. To get them all (instead of an arbitrary one), you can use `WITH TIES`.
- The join to `product` is not needed (assuming there is valid FK).
- You can display all columns from `customer` and other aggregate data if you need them.

Query:

```
SELECT customer.id
       -- customer.*, 
       -- SUM(orderitem.quantity) AS sum
FROM
    orders
    INNER JOIN orderitem ON orders.id = orderitem.orderid
    -- INNER JOIN product ON product.id = orderitem.productid
    INNER JOIN customer ON orders.customerid = customer.id
GROUP BY customer.id
ORDER BY SUM(orderitem.quantity) DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW 
-- WITH TIES
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a window function like `ROW_NUMBER()` in the following manner to generate a unique ID ordered over the records by the `SUM()` of the quantity field. Then you can filter out everything but the record with the highest quantity `SUM()` (SortId = 1).

```
WITH CTE_Quantity_Summed AS -- CTE to calculate the sum of quantity for each customer
(
    SELECT customer.id, customer.firstname, customer.lastname, SUM(quantity) as quantitySum
    FROM orders
    INNER JOIN Orderitem ON orders.id = orderitem.orderid
    INNER JOIN product ON product.id = orderitem.productid
    INNER JOIN Customer ON orders.customerid = customer.id
    GROUP BY customer.id
),
CTE_Quantity_Summed_Sorted AS -- CTE to generate a unique ID per row, sorted by the quantitySum field, descending
(
    SELECT id, firstname, lastname, quantitySum, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY quantitSum DESC) AS SortId
    FROM CTE_Quantity_Summed 
)

SELECT id, firstname, lastname, quantitySum
FROM CTE_Quantity_Summed_Sorted 
WHERE SortId = 1 -- Filters out everything except the row with the highest quantitySum
```

Comment: Note that there could be more than one order with the same maximum sum. Using `row_number()` would only (randomly) pick one of those. Using `rank()` (or `dense_rank()`) would show them all. And since window functions are applied after aggregation, the use of the window function can be pushed down in the first CTE and the second CTE can be omitted completely.

Comment: @stickybit Yup good point. I was still updating my answer to add that infamous clause. Regardless of which window function used, OP will need to make a decision / implement logic to "break the tie". With `ROW_NUMBER()` you just need to add a unique field that makes sense (often times people use just the ID of the source table, meaning whichever record was created first wins the tie). Agreed about being able to simplify into one CTE but figured it may be more clear to the OP how to go from where he currently is (Step 1 / CTE 1) to using a window function to get to his end goal (Step 2 / CTE 2).